# Дергается блок в хроме

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, прокрутка

на сайте есть плавающий блок с баннерами, но когда быстро крутишь колесико вверх-вниз, то он начинает дергаться (только в хроме, в мазиле все норм)

код весь давать не буду, там берутся высота блоков и высчитывается какой отступ сделать, потом этот отступ присваеваеться блоку

```
$('#banner').css({marginTop: asfasf});
```

функция вызывается при скроле страницы

```
$(window).scroll(function(){FloatMenu();});
```

[ссылка на сайт](http://service-list.net/es/es/0/cat/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если оно дёргается, то ничего с этим не сделать, дёргаться и будет.

Однако, можно применить принципиально другое решение: в $(window).scroll() пусть высчитывается только необходимость фиксирования блока, исходя из положения страницы ($(window).scrollTop()) и начального положения баннера ($('#banner').offset()top), и если его нужно фиксировать, назначить класс, в котором прописано position: fixed, иначе же убрать этот класс.

Comment: Спасибо за идею, переделал - работает :)